# What are good films for teaching data-driven decision making? (like Moneyball)

Tags: beginner, reference-request

What are good films for teaching data-driven decision making? In one of my classes, I asked my students to watch Moneyball at home and we discussed it in the class. It was successful and they learned much more than they could by reading a chapter of a textbook.
Are there films with similar theme suitable for my purpose?

Comment: Not a movie, but there is a TV series named "numb3rs", where each episode features a different mathematical model used by the protagonist.

Comment: Numb3rs was ridiculous. He'd have five or six robbery locations, then go "I'm going to use spatial statistics" and then pinpoint the front door of the next robbery. Which is of course where the next robbery happened. I've not seen Moneyball but whenever I've seen stats in a movie it's always been followed by me face-palming (p<0.01).

Answer (score 1):

So while reading an article I came across this list.I have almost watched all them and I think you should too.I hope this helps https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/7-watch-documentaries-statistics-machine-learning/ .

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that 'The big short' is data driven in the sense that a bunch of guys analyse the markets/data and use it to profit by going against preconceived ideas.

You could check out [The Mathematical Movie Database](http://www.qedcat.com/moviemath/) for other ideas.

Id also recommend Nate Silver's book 'The Signal and the Noise: The Art and Science of Prediction' which gives some great insight on applying statistics and data analysis to real world situations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find something about Sports Analytics in the Online Archive of the "11mm - International Football Film Festival Berlin". There are documentaries, short films, feature films. I cannot recommend any, because I haven't seen any of those. Maybe it still helps and you can find something from the descriptions and trailers.

http://www.11-mm.de/index.php/de/ueber-uns/film-archiv

Also, the ~15-minute [TED talks by Hans Rosling](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=ted%20talks%20hans%20rosling), on population growth, global health and economic development are very insightful. Watch the one where he swallows a sword at the end, surprising the audience.